# Search for exact field in an array of strings in elasticsearch

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, text

**Elasticsearch version: 7.1.1**

Hi, I try a lot but could not found any solution
in my index, I have a field which is containing strings.

so, for example, I have two documents containing different values in locations array.

**Document 1:**

```
"doc" : {
            "locations" : [
              "Cloppenburg",
              "Berlin"
           ]
       }
```

**Document 2:**

```
"doc" : {
                "locations" : [
                  "Landkreis Cloppenburg",
                  "Berlin"
                ]
              }
```

a user requests a search for a term **Cloppenburg**
and I want to return only those documents which contain term **Cloppenburg**
and not **Landkreis Cloppenburg**.
the results should contain only **Document-1**.
but my query is returning both documents.

I am using the following query and getting both documents back.
can someone please help me out in this.

```
GET /my_index/_search
     {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "doc.locations": {
                                "query": "cloppenburg",
                                "operator": "and"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to your are using the `text` field and `match` query.

Match queries are analyzed and used the same analyzer of search terms which is used at index time, which is a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) in case of `text` fields. which breaks text on whitespace on in your case `Landkreis Cloppenburg` will create two tokens `landkreis` and `cloppenburg` both index and search time and even `cloppenburg` will match the document.

Solution: Use the `keyword field`.

**Index def**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index your both docs and then use same search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "location": {
                            "query": "Cloppenburg"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

}

**Result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "location",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.6931471,
                "_source": {
                    "location": "Cloppenburg"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: is there any way out?

Comment: @Jawad, nope you need to make these changes, this is how it works :) also its a clean way of doing the things

Comment: Thanks this makes sense and working.
there is another thing if the document has a publishing date.
```
"doc" : {
"datePublished": "2014-11-22T15:06:00.000Z"
            "locations" : [
              "Landkreis Cloppenburg",
              "Berlin"
           ]
       }
```
and sort them with the latest publication date.
Then the result is coming back with the **Landkreis Cloppenburg** if i have this in the query
`
"sort": [
            {
                "doc.datePublished": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            }
        ]
`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263201/search-for-exact-field-in-an-array-of-strings-in-elasticsearch-with-sorting-via