# Search for exact field in an array of strings in elasticsearch with sorting via latest publication date

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

This is a follow-up question of [exact string search in an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212117/search-for-exact-field-in-an-array-of-strings-in-elasticsearch).

There is another thing if the document has a publishing date.

```
{
   "datePublished":"2020-05-22T15:06:00.000Z",
   "locations":[
      "Landkreis Cloppenburg",
      "Berlin"
   ]
}
```

and sort them with the latest publication date.
Then the result is coming back with the **Landkreis Cloppenburg** if I have this in the query:

```
"sort": [
   {
      "doc.datePublished":{
         "order":"desc"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: can you share youe complete query?

Comment: GET article/_search
{
  "sort": [
            {
                "doc.datePublished": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            }
        ], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "locations": {
              "query": "Cloppenburg"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct query should be like below

```
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "datePublished": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "location": {
                "value": "Cloppenburg"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the previous answer was written by me, I just enhanced and included your date field, so my mapping looks like

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "datePublished" : {
                "type" : "date"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are a rockstar, million thanks :) Please upvote my question :)